# How can i read Operarting System Environment variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have set path variable in `Operating system` . I want to access same in `node js` How can I access it ?
I know we can access node environment variable by using `process.env("variablename")` and we can read from `.env` file using `dotenv` .
Suppose I have set `$TEST_PATH = Home/test/`
I want value of `$TEST_PATH` in nodejs.

Comment: [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

Answer (score 1):

When your Node.js process loads, it brings a copy of all the environment variables into context, as an object, for you to access in `process.env`.

So therefor you should be able to access your variable with `process.env.$TEST_PATH`.

For more information, you can have a futher read [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it